# К каким css3 свойствам нужно прописывать префиксы

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите, к каким свойствам CSS-3 нужно прописывать префиксы, а к каким нет? Может есть какой-то список. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не вижу смысла в префиксах. старые mozilla/chrome никто не использует (если уж поставил, значит есть интернет). а в старых IE префиксов никаких нет. по мне бесполезная вещь.

Comment: К тем, которые существуют только с префиксами в тех браузерах, в которых вы ожидаете корректную работу своего сайта.

Comment: Уж не знаю насколько полный список и насколько актуален в принципе, но [посмотрите тут](http://shouldiprefix.com/) (*не забудьте отфильтровать, нажав там кнопку "Show Prefixed"*). Правильно говорят в комментариях выше, можно только добавить, что понятие "нужно прописывать", зависит только от ваших далеко идущих **в прошлое** планах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все уже придумано. Объем свойств с префиксами в коде зависит от количества версий браузеров, которые вы хотите поддержать:
[Автопрефиксер-онлайн](http://autoprefixer.github.io/ru/)

UPD: Поскольку возникли сомнения в релевантности ответа, упомяну еще один сервис - [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/). При поиске по css-свойствам, выдает информацию по поддержке свойств браузерами с разбивкой на версии, в том числе поддержке с учетом префиксов.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/226769)

Comment: Я считаю как раз является ответом. Автор вопроса спросил есть ли список, ответ - есть лучше чем список, есть сервис.

Comment: Ответ на мой вопрос дал Andrey Fedorov, и вправду, чем смотреть по спискам и к каждому Css свойству добавлять префикс, намного легче заюзать этот сервис, который еще и экономит столько времени